# Algorithm to calculate "skippable days" for a 3 times per week habit tracker

Tags: android, algorithm

I have a habit app where you can do something 3 times per week, you can choose which days of the week freely, if all three times that week are finished, I want all other days to be automatically seen as skipped instead of undone.[image: checked = done, horizontal = skipped, no marking = failed]

checked = done, horizontal = skipped, no marking = failed

I've figured it out for future skipped days, but I cant do it for retrospectively skipped days, (week 3 on image you make up for last week by doing twice as much the following week)

```
for(x in data): 
    done = 0
    weekday = 0


    if(x.done) => done += 1
    if(!x.done && done >= TimerPerWeek) => data.markAsSkipped()
    weekday++
    if(weekday = 7) => weekday= 0, done = 0
```

Comment: What relation does the work done in current week hold with work done in the neighboring weeks? What do you want to achieve precisely?

Comment: @AKSingh , the weeks shouldn't be isolated, the other weeks are aware of neighboring weeks and if the user chooses to do 7/7 of days one week, the whole next week is marked as skipped

Comment: For week 3 case, he did 6 days work. So you want to mark the next week as marked skipped automatically,  is that what you need?

Comment: @AKSingh yeah exactly

Comment: Can extra work done on week 1 compensate for no work done on week 3? Suppose on week 1 I do work for 6 days. On week 2 I do work for 3 days. I do no work on week 3. What do you want to happen in this case?

Comment: @AKSingh Both work but preferably there's a limit to it so it won't be skippable if it's a week betwen them.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly the output you asked for, but it does fit your description.

The idea is that each time you did it, it counts towards a maximum of 4 days you can skip within a week.  If 3 times you did the task can be counted towards a day, that day is skipped.  Else not.

```
class Data:
    def __init__ (self, done):
        self.done = done
        self.skipped = False

    def markAsSkipped(self):
        self.skipped = True

def mark_tasks (data):
    avail = []
    for i in range(len(data)):
        if data[i].done:
            avail.append(4)
        else:
            avail.append(0)

    for i in range(len(data)):
        if not data[i].done:
            found = []
            for j in range(max(0, i-6), min(len(data),i+7)):
                if 0 < avail[j]:
                    found.append(j)
                    if 3 <= len(found):
                        for k in found:
                            avail[k] -= 1
                        data[i].markAsSkipped()
                        break


def print_data (data):
    for i in range(6):
        answer = "|"
        for j in range(7):
            cell = data[7*i + j]
            if cell.done:
                answer += "Y"
            elif cell.skipped:
                answer += "-"
            else:
                answer += " "
        answer += "|"
        print(answer)

d = [
    Data(done) for done in [
        True, True, True, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, True, True, True, False, False,
        False, True, True, False, False, False, False,
        True, True, True, True, True, True, False,
        False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False, False, True, True, True,
    ]
]

mark_tasks(d)
print_data(d)
```

Where it differs from your marked output is that Wed of the third week is counted as skipped because of Monday, Tuesday, and the following Sunday.  And Tuesday of the fifth week is counted as skipped because of the previous Wednesday, Thursday and Friday.